# Short soundbite (4-tone-pattern) from "Troy" (2004) used anywhere else?

Tags: soundtrack, sound-effects, troy

The movie "Troy" from 2004 uses a 4-tone-soundbite quite a lot.
It is at the beginning of this:

as well on the 1:12 mark:
[timestamped link to youtube](http://youtu.be/lqDWmpU7DJM?t=1m12s)

I could SWEAR I have heard it used in at least one other movie... but I cannot remember which one!
I hope this is not too vague, but has this 4-tone-scheme been used anywhere else?

Comment: Personally, I prefer the inline video - It's easier to watch it in the question than to have to go to Youtube to view it.

Comment: Inlined the video again

Comment: To be honest, this strikes me as off-topic. By Layna, you're on the right track. You're not the first to notice this 4-note motif in Horner's soundtracks. [Here's a video about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glsyYJksGtg), with examples from 4 different movies.

Comment: Avatar! I cannot find a clip, but I am alost sure it is that scene in avatar during the final battle when the animals where on fire.

Comment: Now Walt put me in a fix... his link absolutely answers my question, because yes, it WAS "Avatar", wich is mentioned in the Video... @Walt, please please make this an answer?

Comment: @Layna OK, putting it up. It's almost like Horner's version of the Wilhelm scream...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's from **every James Horner soundtrack ever.** OK, not really. ;) But he used this 4-note motif a *lot*. Here's a video demonstrating the motif's usage in 3 other films: *Avatar*, *Enemy At the Gates* & *Willow*. (And since Horner composed music for [so many movies](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000035/#composer), there could be others. It even got a name: **The Danger Motif.** This [forum post](http://www.jwfan.com/forums/?app=forums&module=forums&controller=topic&id=19502) even wonders if he ever wrote a soundtrack *without* it...)

Unfortunately, when you work on so many soundtracks, some things are just bound to seep through:

Answer (score 2):

I started the video and my husband heard it out of context and he thought I was watching part of *[Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_II:_The_Wrath_of_Khan)*. He pulled up a video and he's right. It sounds very similar to the motif in the Troy music.

This makes total sense because both soundtracks are composed by [James Horner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Horner#Film).

Here's the piece:

And [here's a video](https://youtu.be/KilBvojsMdw?t=2m45s) from the soundtrack "Battle In The Mutara Nebula" with the specific motif.

Comment: It IS incredibly close, but is not quit what I remmeber... I believe. I wonder if any other movie got closer... But yes, my vague memory may  just have been a SciFi-Movie, too, at least...

Comment: You might look at other films Horner's composed to see if they are what you're looking for. Composers tend to steal their own themes. Link is in the answer.

Comment: It MUST have been one of his! Going throuigh the movie-soundtracks now, ALMOST sure it must have been "Avatar" or "Apolacalypto"!!!

Comment: Woah... someone saw *Apocalypto*?

Comment: LOL, yes. Late night, little on TV, and NO interest in going to bed *G*